Kotlin: Despite converting output of a function to string I still get type mismatch
Good day,
Please take a look on the that simple function.
fun multiplyByTwo(x: Int): String {  // [1]
  println("Inside multiplyByTwo") // [2]
  var result = x * 2
  result = result.toString()
  return result
}

The problem is that although the result is converted to string and I have declared the output to be a string I still get type mismatch.
When I use
var result = (x*2).toString()

instead of
var result = x * 2
  result = result.toString()

it actually works, but it feels like weird java/kotlin under the hood bs despite looking exactly the same.

Please include the exact error message.

Please remember Kotlin is a static typed language. Explanation is really simple: in the first case we initialize the result to an Int, so it is typed as an Int and we can't store a String in it. In the second case we initialize it to String, so it is typed as String.
Your first case is an equivalent to this code:
var result: Int = x * 2
result = result.toString()
return result

If typing explicitly, it is cleaner we try to assign a string to an integer, then we return an integer.

Ahhh. I see. I come from python basis where you have much more elasticity and you can assign a as a number then make it a string. So the only bypass is to create another variable store the result in it and change the type on that stage or simply declare the result to string directly.

As the other answers already explain the reason for the error, this answer will provide more details.
In Kotlin you do not need to explicitly declare the type of a variable in most cases. This is just a convenience feature for the developer, though, because Kotlin is still a statically typed programming language and needs a specific type for each variable at compile time. That's different from languages like JavaScript or Python that check types only at runtime or even allow types to be changed during runtime.
The main benefit of static typing is that the compiler can already check your program for correctness, before you even run it. The Type mismatch error you get is issued by the compiler, you cannot even build the app and execute it and risking a crash on runtime, the compiler nips this in the bud.
Now, when the compiler needs a specific type for each variable, why is this even allowed?
var result = x * 2

Kotlin's static type systen requires a specific type for the variable result, but if you don't explicitly provide one, the compiler will infer the type from the context. You explicitly declared x: Int, so in consequence x * 2 will also be an Int. The compiler allows you to omit the explicit type declaration and silently assumes you have written
var result : Int = x * 2

This is called type inference and is a major feature of Kotlin that mitigates the disadvantages of a statically typed language while still benefitting from its advantages. Compare this to Java, which also has a static type system but where you have to explicitly declare every type yourself, resulting in a lot of boilerplate code.
Back to your issue: When omitting the type it may look as though result would not have a specific type, so this may seem valid:
result = result.toString()

But what you actually try to do is setting a String to an Int variable, hence the Type mismatch error.
You can always hover the mouse over a variable to see which type the compiler infered, which would explain the error you get. Or you can remember to always explicitly declare the type, even when it isn't necessary.
Instead, I would advise you to search your IDE for an option to display the infered types inline, so you can always keep an eye on them and verify that they meet your expectations. Like this, for example:

In IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio that can be enabled by ticking the following checkbox in the settings:
Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Types -> Kotlin

Now you can have your cake and eat it too:

Benefit from the static type system, preventing a lot of runtime errors.
Clean code without unnecessary type declarations.
Good overview of the actual types used, making the reason for the error in your question obvious.


These are not the same thing, because Kotlin is statically typed language.
In the first case, you declare the variable result as Int, because x*2 is of Int type, as far as x is of Int type. And later try to assign a String value to it. Of course, this causes a type mismatch exception.
In the second case, you declare the variable as String from the very beginning, and assign a String to it latet. Everything is fine here. No error occurs.

Kotlin supports type inference and automatically identifies the data type of a declared variable.
Refer more details variables.
so its taken variable type as Int  from this line
var result = x * 2

But next line you try to assign the string value into Int Type
result = result.toString() 
// result is Int but you assign String value

your case Its should be
  var result = (x*2).toString()

